# Google Cloud Run as POJO?

Tags: google-cloud-run

Is it possible to write a Google Cloud Run service in Java as a plain old java object (POJO)?  More specifically, is it possible and are there examples of how to do it without Spring Boot?  We don't use Spring and have no interest in it.  Yet all the examples use Spring Boot.

Comment: If you’re wanting to keep things simple. You could use the Cloud Functions sample as a base. All the Java needs to do is expose a port on 8080 (or $PORT), and handle a http request. Functions framework will help with that: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-java

Comment: As long as you can package your app as a container Cloud Run Can run it. Follow any guide to package a POJO to a docker container, make your app listen on the env variable PORT and it should work!

Comment: Cloud functions seems pretty easy to build and deploy.  

Building a docker contains involves too many steps.  Google needs to simplify it.

Comment: You may send a feedback on that specific Documentation, so that the Product team will notified about your concern.

Comment: Don't get me started on Google Documentation.  In my opinion, it is so horrendous, if Google fired that entire deparatment that writs GCP documentation, it would be a good start.

Comment: On a more positive note, I too Paul's suggestion. Cloud Functions is a good fit.  The documentation is not that great, but I got through it.  Even wrapped one CF around a Cloud Task to keep it asynchronous.  Oh, CF is a good intro to Cloud Run since it is built on Cloud Run.